# Need to remove scrollbar displaying in IE8 for embed player

Tags: html, css, wordpress, embed, video-player

I'm using gigya service for video embed...

If some one paste the following code in his wordpress page or post then horizontal and vertical scrollbar is displaying only in IE browsers....Working fine in Firefox and Chrome..

Here is the code:-

```
[gigya src="http://s.asstatic.com/player.swf" width="425" height="354" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" flashvars="file=fb=0&nb=1&ap=0&pl=as&c=#dfdfdf&p=1615781_634907097231053940"]
```

Please help me what should i put in the above code to remove the scrollbar displaying in IE only...

and here is the links.. please open it in IE8 or IE7...

http://gauravishere.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/test/

Thanks...

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: please check the above link in IE and Firefox... found my question...:)   I need to remove the scrollbar in IE when i paste the Gigya embed code in wordpress page or post....

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question? If so, please create an answer below and mark as answer so that others in the future with the same question may find their answer more easily. Thank you.

Comment: 'position:absolute' works for me...Lets see.. this the right option or not...

Comment: If that answered your question then please post it as an answer below and mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

position:absolute' works for me...

```
[gigya src="..." style="position:absolute" width="425" height="354" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" flashvars="file=fb=0&nb=1&ap=0&pl=as&c=#dfdfdf&p=99..."]
```

Answer (score -1):

try to fix this type of issue by:

1. Use html5 doctype if possible:
2. Set 100% on all parent containers:

   *, html, body { height: 100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }